# Most pythonic way of counting on the fly using a loop and dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I often find my self using a dict to count the occurences of something, and I wonder if there is a way of doing this more smooth without using exceptions.

```
count_dict = {} 
for file in files:
    ############
    #parse file#
    ############
    for line in lines:
        tokens = line.split()
        if "something" in tokens:
            try:
                count_dict[tokens[0]] += 1
            except KeyError:
                count_dict[tokens[0]] = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Python has a class specifically for this: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
count_dict = Counter(str.split())
```